# Using Django Auth without a traditional username/password login and only Twitter login

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am familiar with using django's built-in auth to create a new user that has an email and password, but I would like to create a new user that will only use Twitter to login.  From what I can tell, django-social-auth associates the twitter account with an existing Django User object.  In my case, there will not be an existing Django User object, as Twitter will be the required method for logging into the site.  Should I abandon django's built in auth? Or is there a good way to extend it to do what I want?  Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django-social-auth extends django  built-in auth. django-social-auth will create it self a new user whem your Twitter user will be successfully authenticate. You can [read about django-social-auth features](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/#features):

- Basic user data population and signaling, to allows custom fields values from providers response.
- Multiple social accounts association to single users
- Custom User model override if needed (auth.User by default)
- Extensible pipeline to handle authentication/association mechanism